# Why does a specific algorithm take significantly longer through ctypes?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a C program that measures how long certain algorithms take to insert an element into a data structure using clock()

All my various functions.. closed hashing table, open hashing table, binary search tree, red black tree.. all of them seem to take just as long when executed standalone as when called through ctypes

EXCEPT one. My AVL tree. It takes about 100 ms for 200000 elements in C, but 3600ms for only 10000 elements in ctypes. What could the culprit be? Why does this generally happen? I thought calling the func through ctypes is the same as running a compiled executable.

My AVL tree:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "funcs.h"

struct node_m{
    unsigned long int val;
    struct node_m * left;
    struct node_m * right;
    int height;
};

struct node_m * root;
unsigned char flag_g;

int max(struct node_m * x, struct node_m * y){
    int a;
    int b;
    if(x == NULL){
        a = 0;
    } else
        a = x->height;
    if(y == NULL){
        b = 0;
    } else
        b = y->height;
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

struct node_m * r_rot(struct node_m * temp){
    struct node_m * temp_d = temp->left;
    struct node_m * temp_dd = temp_d->right;

    temp_d->right = temp;
    temp->left = temp_dd;
    temp->height = 1 + max(temp->left, temp->right);
    temp_d->height = 1 + max(temp_d->left, temp_d->right);

    return temp_d;
}

struct node_m * l_rot(struct node_m * temp){
    struct node_m * temp_d = temp->right;
    struct node_m * temp_dd = temp_d->left;

    temp_d->left = temp;
    temp->right = temp_dd;
    temp->height = 1 + max(temp->left, temp->right);
    temp_d->height = 1 + max(temp_d->left, temp_d->right);

    return temp_d;
}

struct node_m * insert_m(struct node_m * node, unsigned long int val){
    if(node == NULL){
        struct node_m * leaf = malloc(sizeof(struct node_m));
        leaf->height = 1;
        leaf->val = val;
        leaf->left = NULL;
        leaf->right = NULL;
        return leaf;
    }else if(node->val > val){
        node->left = insert_m(node->left, val);
    } else if(node->val < val){
        node->right = insert_m(node->right, val);
    } else {
        return node;
    }

    if(!flag_g) {
        node->height = 1 + max(node->left, node->right);
        int l, r;

        if (node->left == NULL) {
            l = 0;
        } else
            l = node->left->height;

        if (node->right == NULL) {
            r = 0;
        } else
            r = node->right->height;

        int balance = l - r;

        if (balance < -1 && val > node->right->val) {
            node = l_rot(node);
            return node;
        }

        if (balance < -1 && val < node->right->val) {
            node->right = r_rot(node->right);
            node = l_rot(node);
            return node;
        }

        if (balance > 1 && val < node->left->val) {
            node = r_rot(node);
            return node;
        }

        if (balance > 1 && val > node->left->val) {
            node->left = l_rot(node->left);
            node = r_rot(node);
            return node;
        }
    }

    return node;
}

float driver_mytree(int x, unsigned char flag) {
    unsigned long int * randlist = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    floyd_rand(&randlist, x);
    flag_g = 0;
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node_m));
    root->height = 1;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->val = randlist[0];
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++){
        root = insert_m(root, randlist[i]);
    }
    if(flag){
        flag_g = flag;
        start = clock();
        for(int i = x - 1; i > 0; i--){
            root = insert_m(root, randlist[i]);
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();

    return (float) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
}
```

My python testing file

```py
import ctypes

testlib = ctypes.CDLL("./lib.so")

testlib.driver_mytree.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint64, ctypes.c_int]
testlib.driver_mytree.restype = ctypes.c_float
my_tree = testlib.driver_mytree

x = my_tree(10000, 0)
print(x)
```

This is how I compiled the individual files:

```
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC bvs.c    -o mybuild/bvs.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC my_hash.c    -o mybuild/my_hash.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC my_tree.c    -o mybuild/my_tree.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC rand.c    -o mybuild/rand.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC pcg_basic.c -o mybuild/pcg_basic.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC their_hash.c    -o mybuild/their_hash.o
gcc -c -std=c11 -fPIC their_tree.c    -o mybuild/their_tree.o


gcc -shared mybuild/pcg_basic.o mybuild/rand.o mybuild/bvs.o mybuild/my_hash.o mybuild/my_tree.o mybuild/their_tree.o mybuild/their_hash.o -o lib.so

pause
```

Note: I know I'm passing int to unsigned char flag but it works with the other ones just fine

Comment: In C the function is called `driver_mytree` but in python you call `driver_myhash`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: I am suspicious about `temp->height = 1 + max(temp->left, temp->right);
    temp_d->height = 1 + max(temp_d->left, temp_d->right);` hmmm,

Comment: The myhash was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: `testlib.driver_mytree.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ubyte]`.

Comment: Today I tried it again, and now it runs normally, with no changes to the code. I am confused

Comment: Can you post the driver for the C test ? Also, the 'driver_mytree' allocate lot of memory, but never free anything. This might interact badly with python memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found.

It resided in how a random generation function called PCG works.
Since it generated random numbers and had a 'memory' for even distribution,
because I combined it with my knuth algorithm for making arrays of unique random
numbers, it would get stuck in a long loop.